# Fit Poisson binomial distribution to data

Tags: r, data-fitting, poisson, fitdistrplus

I keep hitting the same error when trying to fit distribution to data using `fitdistrplus`. MWE is below. In short, I want to fit a Poisson binomial distribution to some data. I'm using the `poibin` R package for the Poisson binomial p,d,q,r functions (I've also tried `poisbinom` with same error). In the MWE I create `dd`, the vector of successes. I'm trying to use `fitdist` then to fit the distribution given the starting values in the `start` list. The error says (I think) that I'm giving it start values that have names that aren't in the `dpoibin` function, which is where I'm stuck.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(poibin)
set.seed(123)
dd <- rpoibin(10, pp=seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out=10))
ppp <- runif(10)
ret <- try(fitdistrplus::fitdist(dd, distr=dpoibin,
    start=list(pp = ppp)))
```

Error message:

> Error in checkparamlist(arg_startfix$start.arg, arg_startfix$fix.arg,  :
> 'start' must specify names which are arguments to 'distr'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the function `fitdistrplus:::checkparamlist`, which is called by `fitdist` to ensure the names in the list passed to `start` match the parameter names in the function passed to `distr`. When you pass a vector like `ppp` as a parameter in `start`, `checkparamlist` renames each element of the vector by appending an integer. This means the argument names become `"pp1", "pp2", "pp3"` and so on up to `"pp10"`. Since there is no argument being passed called `pp`, an error is thrown.

I'm not sure if there is a way to estimate vectorized parameters in `fitdist` due to this problem, but fortunately in this case we can easily just fit the distribution ourselves.

Since we know the mean of the distribution is

[image]

and the variance is

[image]

[(Reference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution)

Then we know that if we have a sample `dd`, the following function will return 0 if `pp` fits the distribution perfectly:

```r
objective <- function(pp) {
  abs(mean(dd) - sum(pp)) + abs(sum(pp * (1 - pp)) - var(dd))
}
```

To demonstrate this works, let's take a much larger sample from `rpoibin`

```r
set.seed(123)

dd  <- poibin::rpoibin(100000, pp=seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out=10))
ppp <- runif(10)
```

Now we find the set of values that optimizes our objective function:

```r
pp_opt <- optim(par = ppp, objective)$par

pp_opt
#>  [1] 0.45594175 0.08754997 0.54250499 0.28056432 0.30363457 0.28354584
#>  [7] 0.17861750 0.21109410 0.41562763 0.23920435
```

We can confirm this is a good fit by plotting a histogram and overlay the output of `dpoibin` with our calculated values for the `pp` parameter:

```r
hist(dd, freq = FALSE, breaks = 0:11 - 0.5)
points(0:10, poibin::dpoibin(0:10, pp = pp_opt), col = "red")
```

[image]

Note that there could be many solutions to the optimal value of `pp`, and we should not expect to get `seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 10)`. For a start, order does not make a difference. We can see our `pp_opt` has a very similar mean and  variance to `seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 10)`, which is all that matters in terms of fitting the distribution

```r
mean(seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 10))
#> [1] 0.3
mean(pp_opt)
#> [1] 0.2998285

sum((1 - pp_opt) * pp_opt)
#> [1] 1.930687
sum((1 - seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 10)) * seq(0.1, 0.5, length.out = 10))
#> [1] 1.937037
```

In general, it is not possible to recover `pp` exactly from a given sample due to the ordering and the fact that an infinite number of sets have the same distribution and calculated variance.

<sup>Created on 2023-07-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you change `set.seed(123); n=100; rpoibin(n, ...` and gives negative probabilities. You can force the params to be greater than 0 with `lower=0, method="L-BFGS-B"` in `optim` (although perhaps you can reparmeterise your function, which I'm too lazy to think about). As an alt to your objective, i think oyu could use the log-likelihood: `ll = function(par, x) -sum(log(dpoibin(x, par)))`

Comment: ... although further testing seems to show that the log-lik optimisation is a bit funky on the lower limit for smaller samples

Comment: @user20650 good point. The `optim` call needs to be bounded between 0 and 1. Changed.

Comment: ... and the sensitivity in the loglik seems due to  log(density(..) returning -Inf